# how to write Assert.istrue in selenium c#?

Tags: c#, selenium

> Christmas Deliveries
>
> Please try to have your order placed by November 24th to avoid Christmas postal delays

I want to test the above text on page .. check my coding i keep geting the test failed

```
var notice2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/form[@id='aspnetForm']/div[@class='wrapper']/div[@class='wrapper_inside ']/div[@class='content_right']/div[@class='scn_full']/div[@class='special_panel'][2]/div[@class='special_holder']/div[@class='special_block']/div[3]"));
Assert.IsTrue(driver.PageSource.Contains("Please try to have your order placed by November 25th to avoid Christmas postal delays"));
```

Comment: The dates are different between your example text and your assertion. Is that intentional?

Comment: i corrected the date still same problem showing error message as

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML. Have you tried printing the contained text? My guess is there's some extra character somewhere that is causing the comparison failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you posted the html as Jeff mentioned. Your xpath is highly brittle so I would suggest fixing that.

Basically what you want to do is something like:

Get the text value of the element:

```
var notice2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//myNewXPath")).Text;
```

Then Assert the values are equal:

```
Assert.AreEqual(notice2, "Please try to have your order placed by November 25th to avoid Christmas postal delays");
```